# Crash after export to assets and warning "connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died"

Tags: ios, ios8, assets

I received strange warning

"connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died"

and crash some after without output to console while working with assets.
I save processed video to assets. After several savings application starts glitch and crashes without any output.

Crash shows nothing - just Xcode message "connection with device lost".

Comment: I am facing the same problem. if you have found any solution or work around for this then please share

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if my issue is related to Pawan Kumar Sharma's problem.
But the problem was related to retain cycle in my code responsible for recording video.
So it was memory problem.
After fixing retain cycle memory warnings and this strange warning disappeared.